# How to display VM's memory in sort when using xm top in SUSE 11

Tags: suse

Like `df -Ph` can show the used size of mount in human-readable style, how can I make a human-readable showing when using `xm top` in SUSE 11?

Also does anyone know how to display VM's memory in sort when using xm top in SUSE 11 or SUSE 12?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNc0d.jpg)

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: Who can give help?

Answer (score 0):

While using `xm top` press 's' - this cycles through the sort order. The currently sorted column has a bold header.

See https://linux.die.net/man/1/xentop

I think there is no way to make the output human readable.